# How to restrict artifactory oauth access?

Tags: artifactory

I run an artifactory pro cloud instance and I added OAuth github authentication.

It works fine but anyone can login that my instance, I didn't find any place/way to restrict only to users part of my github organization.

Any tip please? Maybe I'm taking from the wrong angle?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Well, there is a bug filled for that.
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14301